# Need to size StackView proportionately to my device size

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I am building my screen in code which contains a stackView that holds my textfields.  This stackView looks great on an iPhone 8/8Plus/X device, but too large on an SE screen.  I realize that I need to size my stackView proportionately to the device size, but am not sure how programmatically.  All the tutorials that I've seen show how to do it in IB.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
        let textFieldStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [nameTextField, emailTextField, passwordTextField])
        textFieldStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textFieldStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        textFieldStackView.axis = .vertical
        textFieldStackView.spacing = 10

        view.addSubview(textFieldStackView)

        textFieldStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        textFieldStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        textFieldStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true
        textFieldStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

It's not just the width, but the height as well which I need to grow accordingly.  How would I do this in code?

Comment: What do you mean by sizing it proportionally? Can you describe it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I would like the height and width to increase by the same amount, depending on which screen size they are on.

Comment: You are too vague.. you want it to be a 1/2 of the screen height? you want it to fill the rest of the screen?

Comment: If you want the stack view's size to be relative to the main view's size, why are you using `equalToConstant` for your constraints? Your code makes no sense given your claims about what you want to do.

Comment: @matt This is why I'm asking a question.  As I pointed out, I'm unsure how to do this, as the tutorials that show how to do this, are using IB, and not code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to clip your view to edges of you screen you should use safeArea for top/bottom constraints and leading and trailing margin for leading and trailing constraints. This way your view will look great on any device you need.
EG:

```
yourView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
yourView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
yourView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
yourView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

It's ios 11 code. For support of iOS 10 layout use for top and bottom anchors of controller use self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor and self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor.
It's much correct to use autolayout in autolayout, not UISCreenSizes as in top comment. 
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/ learn this guide, it's little helps.

EDIT:
If you want to have your view in the center and change its size depending on screen size and same time having equal spacing leading and trailing the best way i see is to use supporting views on the left and right ofyour view, which will have same widths. Adjusting compression resistance on center (your) view you will make it to become thinner of wider.
Something like this:
[image: Example]

EDIT2:
Based on your comment and in code:

```
yourView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
yourView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
yourView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
yourView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
yourView.bottomAnchor.constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
yourView.topAnchor.constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
yourView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
yourView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
```

Comment: How would I apply the safeArea for my view if I'm using the center constraint?

Comment: Safe area is useful for top/bottom constraints. If you want to conntect you view to center of your master view your must use it's center constraint.  
yourView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: Ok, i got it. I recommended not what you wanted.  
You need to have view in the center of screen, which will resize itself depending on screen's width? Placed in the center and having same spacing leading and trailing?

Comment: Close, I would like it to resize itself based on both screen width, and height, placed in the center with leading, and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the values from one device screen (6S in the example below) to another..

```
func ScaleWidth(CGFloat value) -> CGFloat {
    return round(value * (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(375.0)));
}

func ScaleHeight(CGFloat value) -> CGFloat {
    return round(value * (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / CGFloat(667.0)));
}



textFieldStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: ScaleHeight(100.0)).isActive = true
textFieldStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ScaleHeight(150.0)).isActive = true
textFieldStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ScaleWidth(350.0)).isActive = true
textFieldStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Another option is to use the constraint multiplier:

```
func AspectWidth() -> CGFloat {
    return round(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(375.0));
}

func AspectHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return round(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / CGFloat(667.0));
}



textFieldStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100.0, multiplier: AspectHeight()).isActive = true
textFieldStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0, multiplier: AspectHeight()).isActive = true
textFieldStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350.0, multiplier: AspectWidth()).isActive = true
textFieldStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (but not the prettiest one) is to use `UIScreen.main.frame` to calculate the constants of your constraints. `UIScreen.main.frame` represents the frame of the whole screen and is different on each device (320x568 on iPhone SE, 375x667 on iPhone 8).

Your code could look like this if you would like the stack view to look the same on each device:

```
    let textFieldStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [nameTextField, emailTextField, passwordTextField])
    textFieldStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textFieldStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    textFieldStackView.axis = .vertical
    textFieldStackView.spacing = UIScreen.main.frame.height / 66.7 // will be 10 on iPhone 8

    view.addSubview(textFieldStackView)

    textFieldStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: UIScreen.main.frame.height / 6.67).isActive = true
    textFieldStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.frame.height / 4.45).isActive = true
    textFieldStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.frame.width / 1.07).isActive = true
    textFieldStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on an answer of kiwisip, so I have to write it here - using `UIScreen.main.frame` isn't a good solution, it's better to rely on size of view, in which you add your stack view as subview. In your example, you have to replace `widthAnchor` constraint with something like this:

```
textFieldStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

On the other hand - using superview sizes divided by constant instead of just using constant values can be a good idea, but it depends on your layout.

Comment: It might and might not be. Depends on the situation. I think using `UIScreen.main.frame` is more universal and better suited for this question.